# run a block on main thread immediately after NSBlockOperation on background thread

Tags: multithreading, macos, swift, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

In my project I run an operation on a background thread using `NSBlockOperation`:

```
var operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
var iop = NSBlockOperation(block: { self.reloadSize() /*calculation...*/ })
operationQueue.addOperation(iop)
```

Immediately after the calculations in the background thread are completed, I need to call: `table.reloadData()` on an NSTableView. I would do that in the very same thread, however, due to auto layout issues, the table has to be reloaded on the main thread. How can I accomplish this asynchronous relationship across both threads?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

1. Dispatch the reloading of the table from inside the block:

   ```
   let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
   let operation = NSBlockOperation() {
       self.reloadSize()
       ...
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { // or you can use NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock()
           self.table.reloadData()
       }
   }
   operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
   ```

   or just use `addOperationWithBlock`:

   ```
   let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
   operationQueue.addOperationWithBlock() {
       self.reloadSize()
       ...
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { // or you can use NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock()
           self.table.reloadData()
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a new operation dependent upon this one:

   ```
   let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

   let operation = NSBlockOperation() {
       self.reloadSize()
       ...
   }

   let completionOperation = NSBlockOperation() {
       self.table.reloadData()
   }

   completionOperation.addDependency(operation)

   operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
   NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperation(completionOperation)
   ```

Personally, I'd generally lean towards the first approach, though the latter approach can be useful in more complicated scenarios (e.g. the completion operation is dependent upon a number of other operations).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for providing alternate options.

Answer (score -1):

Try calling CFRunLoopRun().
It should run in the current queue.

If your operation ran on main queue, the current queue would be main queue and the operation would run on it succesfully